# SwiftUI Two Row NavigationBar

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way using SwiftUI to get a two row NavigationBar like instagram has? Even better would be two rows with a fullwidth search bar like in the image.

ex.
[image]

Comment: will this suit your needs? https://imgur.com/a/3HLaZOV ? if yes let me know i'll post it as an answer and later on i'll refactor the design, i just did it quickly however of course the design can be redesigned to be much better :)

Comment: Looks pretty close to the image above!

Comment: i posted the code for you, and it can be redesigned to look nicer and similar to instagram i'll make sure to update the answer and make it as close as possible to instagram for example you need to remove the navigation top bar, also when you click on photo you need to present the view on the whole screen...and so on

Answer (score 1):

Here you go an example close to the image, of course it can be redesigned to suit your needs I did it very quickly it doesn't look nice, but as I said it can be redesigned to look much nicer:

```
@State var testok = ""

var body: some View {
        VStack {
        
        VStack {
            TextField("search here man", text: $testok)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 40)
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("ok")
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    
                    Text("yumyum")
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    
                    Text("lool")
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    
                    Text("pewpew")
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("ok")) {
                    Text("ok")
                     .navigationTitle(Text("navigation title"))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see how you did that. Do you think Instagram is using the NavigationBar in their implementation?

Comment: @1dolinski Let me say yes and no, yes becuase when i click on certain things i get the navigationView behaviour, and on certain things no, when i click on them i get a normal scrollview behaviour that get expanded by ZStack to cover all the screen.

Comment: Do you know how I could get 2 rows like theirs with the NavigationBar?

Comment: For me i think that 2 rows they are not navigationView because i took a second look now and i saw:

1) i looked at some posts and i see that they are all a normal view only they videos of tiktok they act like they are in a navigationView but they are not.
2) when you click on a post it will cover the whole screen and it can be done by geometry so i don't think they are using navigation view at all.

You can have a look also at tutorials the ones that they make instagram swiftui and see.